# Terminate rogue "tor" process

Tags: linux, networking, tor, kill-process

I have a rogue tor process running on my system. I am using a linux machine. I tried to locate the pid of that process using `lsof -i:9050 and lsof -i|grep 'tor'`

I was not able to find anything on it. Below is the error thrown:

```
May 09 22:57:15.981 [notice] Tor v0.2.3.25 (git-17c24b3118224d65) running on Linux.
May 09 22:57:15.981 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
May 09 22:57:15.981 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
May 09 22:57:15.986 [warn] ControlPort is open, but no authentication method has been configured.  This means that any program on your computer can reconfigure your Tor.  That's bad!  You should upgrade your Tor controller as soon as possible.
May 09 22:57:15.986 [notice] Initialized libevent version 1.4.13-stable using method epoll. Good.
May 09 22:57:15.986 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
May 09 22:57:15.986 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
May 09 22:57:15.000 [warn] It looks like another Tor process is running with the same data directory.  Waiting 5 seconds to see if it goes away.
May 09 22:57:20.000 [err] No, it's still there.  Exiting.
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

How did a rogue tor process get to your system? Did you install it there and then forgot where, or were you hacked? If the later, skip the next paragraph.

You can search for the TCP ports that tor listens on, and get the process ID from there. Run `netstat -anp` and search for someone listening on the relevant port. If you're not sure what the port is, I suggest using a network sniffer (such as `tcpdump` or `wireshark`). The above command, if run as root, will give you the pid of the listening process.

If you cannot find the port there, or if it is there, but the process still does not show up on ps and kill, then it is likely that you have been hacked. Modern rootkits can hide their processes and files, so that you cannot access them even if you know where they are. If so, do not bother with killing the process. You have bigger problems.

There is no generic effective way to remove a rootkit from a compromised system. Your *only* good course of action under those circumstances is to reinstall the system. Also, try to find what door was used to hack you (usually an out of date service) and close it.

**Edited to add**
`netstat -anp` will work even if you are not root. You will only see your own user's PIDs, but that is probably enough for what you are trying to do here.

Also, if tor is running as a byproduct of something you are doing, then strace might be your friend:
`strace -e execve -f -o /tmp/trace` will output to /tmp/trace any execve calls done by your process and any of its children. You can just grep for tor there and see what the PID is, and from there figure out how to find it in the generic case.

Comment: I am trying to run a program which uses tor service. The host is a public system in my library. I will check with the administrator to see if he can terminate the rogue process.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to be root to run the `lsof` commands you tried because Tor must be running as a different user if nothing is coming back.

If Tor is not erroneously telling you another process is already running with the same data directory, there are a few things you can do.

- Just use the existing Tor process instead of running your own (look at `/etc/tor/torrc` for configuration details)
- Change your `DataDirectory` (and ports if necessary) to something else so you can run them side by side

It says in the logs the ControlPort is open with no authentication.  You can try this to get the PID of the existing process:

```
> telnet localhost 9051
> AUTHENTICATE
< 250 OK
> GETINFO process/pid
< 250-process/pid=2297
< 250 OK
```

Comment: I used sudo for `lsof`. I figured out what was my problem. There was a nologin user who is running tor. I restart it using `/etc/init.d/tor`